# All the messages from SQS goes into DLQ even after successful execution of Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

```
Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
Properties:
  QueueName: "notification-service-queue.fifo"
  FifoQueue: true
  ContentBasedDeduplication: true
  VisibilityTimeout: 180
  FifoThroughputLimit: perMessageGroupId
  DeduplicationScope: messageGroup 
  RedrivePolicy:
    deadLetterTargetArn: ${self:custom.DLQ_ARN}
    maxReceiveCount: 2
```

This is my queue configuration, as you can see, it hs high throughput enabled. I am doing batch processing, so a batch of 10 is sent to the queue and the lambda quickly gets triggered, it runs successfully and returns this response "Successfully Processed". What I don't understand is, the messages are not getting automatically deleted. The entire batch is going into DLQ even after successfully processing. Can anyone help me here?

Comment: you have to delete the message in the lambda `SQS.DeleteMesage({   "QueueUrl": "string",   "ReceiptHandle": "string" })`

if you don't delete , the message is "in flight" and after the visibility time is expired, the message will reappear in the queue again. After retry count is exceeded, the message drops into the DLQ

Comment: @gusto2 that's not true for Lambda functions configured with an SQS event source. The Lambda service handles deleting the messages, if the function returns a success code.

Comment: @gusto2 *you* don't have to delete the batch of messages from SQS. If your triggered Lambda function completes its processing of the batch, it can simply exit normally and the Lambda service will delete the messages from SQS.

Comment: We need to see your Lambda function's source code.